# How can i create Featured Image function in core php not in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, oop

There is a function for every page in wordpress so if we share link in other websites then it fetches title, description and featured image of that page / post, but i wanna make this functionality in core php not in wordpress, how can i make it so when i share link to other website then  it fetches only that one featured image ? without featured image functionality it fetches only logo.

please could you help me?

Comment: You will need to include og:image meta tag in the head section of the page. Learn more at http://ogp.me/

Comment: and that tag will fetches only one that og:image ?

Comment: You will have to populate the desired image URL in the "content" attribute of that tag. Then that image will be fetched by other websites (like facebook) when share the URL.

Comment: og:image is not working brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is add OpenGraph on your PHP/HTML header.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Your desired title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Some sentences here" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.yourdomain.com/filename.php" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="rumahweb.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.yourdomain.com/featured-image.png" />
```

Insert above code (and adjust the value as necessary) inside your HEAD section of your HTML/PHP file.